# Visual Studio 2017 lock file in solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, solution

I have a C# application, a VS2017 solution with 7 projects.

Is it possible to lock a *.cs file or a project in order to avoid me to do undesired modification?

Comment: Use a source control solution (TFVC, Git, SVN) and check the files you commit

Comment: Imho you should not rely on file locking but Source Control.

Comment: Make the file read-only from file system (Windows Explorer).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is [source control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/source-control).  Using systems like [TFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server), [Git](https://git-scm.com/), or [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/), you can track changes, see who has changed what, roll back to previous states, and in some cases, mark files as read-only.  Without source control, marking a file in the file system as read-only is your only real option.

A server is not required for source control.  While some solutions do require one, Git and SVN can be entirely local.